# How do I get the class name of an object from "an instance with class-id XX"?

Tags: toit

I'm trying to print an object in Toit with `print o`, but I'm only getting
When printing an object it only shows "an instance with class-id 12".

Here is a small example:

```
class A:

main:
  o := A
  print o
```

which prints:

```
an instance with class-id 42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `stringify` method of `Object` does not include the name of the class. This is to save space. However, an unstripped snapshot does.

If you first compile your program to a snapshot (`toit.compile -w app.snapshot app.toit`) then you can use `toitp` to inspect the snapshot. For example `toitp --classes app.snapshot` lists all classes with their ids.

The `toit.compile` executable is located in the `bin` folder of the SDK, and the `toitp` program is located in the `tools` folder of the SDK.

You can download the SDK either from https://github.com/toitlang/toit, or, if you use Jaguar, it is also cached in `~/.cache/jaguar/sdk` (and a similar path on Windows).